# Jenkins Job DSL: how to build particular node in Configure block?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

The particular thing I want is to prevent some steps from execution in Flexible Publish section. I use a condition of strings (not) matching and I don't want something to be executed after check fails.

Being configured manually, expected step looks like this:
[Expected postbuild step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqmnW.png)

As I have not found an appropriate method in [Jenkins Jobs DSL API](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/) I've tried to reproduce it using the Configure block. The reference says that I can use 'project' for root element of the job and 'node' for particular node to append a child to them. It says also that new nodes won't be created again if pointed nodes exist. So here's my config:

```
job("flexible_condition") {

  publishers {

    flexiblePublish {
      configure { node ->
          node / publishers /
          'org.jenkins__ci.plugins.flexible__publish.ConditionalPublisher' << 'runner'(class:
          'org.jenkins_ci.plugins.run_condition.BuildStepRunner$DontRun')
        }

      condition {
        not { stringsMatch('string_placeholder', '', false) }
      }

      publisher {
        debianPackage('common') {
          commitMessage('new feature')
        }
      }

      publisher {
        git {
          pushOnlyIfSuccess(true)
          branch('origin', 'master')
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In spite of the reference desirable xml aren't generated in my jenkins neither in the Playground. I've got nodes duplicated instead and it seems that 'node' is interpreted as 'project' and is always put to the root.

```
<!-- 1. flexible_condition -->
<project>
    <actions></actions>
    <description></description>
    <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
    <properties></properties>
    <scm class='hudson.scm.NullSCM'></scm>
    <canRoam>true</canRoam>
    <disabled>false</disabled>
    <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
    <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
    <triggers class='vector'></triggers>
    <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
    <builders></builders>
    <publishers>
        <org.jenkins__ci.plugins.flexible__publish.ConditionalPublisher>
            <runner     class='org.jenkins_ci.plugins.run_condition.BuildStepRunner$DontRun'></runner>
        </org.jenkins__ci.plugins.flexible__publish.ConditionalPublisher>
        <org.jenkins__ci.plugins.flexible__publish.FlexiblePublisher>
            <publishers>
                <org.jenkins__ci.plugins.flexible__publish.ConditionalPublisher>
                    <condition     class='org.jenkins_ci.plugins.run_condition.logic.Not'>
                        <condition     class='org.jenkins_ci.plugins.run_condition.core.StringsMatchCondition'>
                            <arg1>string_placeholder</arg1>
                            <arg2></arg2>
                            <ignoreCase>false</ignoreCase>
                        </condition>
                    </condition>
                    <publisherList>
                        <ru.yandex.jenkins.plugins.debuilder.DebianPackagePublisher>
                            <repoId>common</repoId>
                            <commitMessage>new feature</commitMessage>
                            <commitChanges>true</commitChanges>
                            </ru.yandex.jenkins.plugins.debuilder.DebianPackagePublisher>
                        <hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher>
                            <configVersion>2</configVersion>
                            <pushMerge>false</pushMerge>
                            <pushOnlyIfSuccess>true</pushOnlyIfSuccess>
                            <forcePush>false</forcePush>
                            <tagsToPush></tagsToPush>
                            <branchesToPush>
                                <hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher_-BranchToPush>
                                        <targetRepoName>origin</targetRepoName>
                                    <branchName>master</branchName>
                                </hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher_-BranchToPush>
                            </branchesToPush>
                        </hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher>
                    </publisherList>
                    <runner class='org.jenkins_ci.plugins.run_condition.BuildStepRunner$Fail'></runner>
                </org.jenkins__ci.plugins.flexible__publish.ConditionalPublisher>
            </publishers>
        </org.jenkins__ci.plugins.flexible__publish.FlexiblePublisher>
    </publishers>
    <buildWrappers></buildWrappers>
</project>
```

I've been checking this example in the Playground via Job DSL version 1.40 but 1.39 in my jenkins gives the same result.

What am doing wrong?

Thank you.

**UPD** I've put the configure block below as SevenEleven suggested and it almost helped. The runner node is on the right place now but is still duplicated.

```
<publishers>
    <org.jenkins__ci.plugins.flexible__publish.ConditionalPublisher>
        <condition .../>
        <publisherList>
            ...
        </publisherList>
        <runner class='org.jenkins_ci.plugins.run_condition.BuildStepRunner$Fail'></runner>
        <runner class='org.jenkins_ci.plugins.run_condition.BuildStepRunner$DontRun'></runner>
    </org.jenkins__ci.plugins.flexible__publish.ConditionalPublisher>
</publishers>
```

**UPD 2** Although there are two different lines in the xml, the newer runner replaces the default one in generated job. So I've got the expected result. Thanks.

**UPD 3**. Yay! Found out that now one can simply use JobDSL syntax and it works.

```
publishers {

  flexiblePublish {
    conditionalAction {
      condition {
          not { stringsMatch('string_placeholder', '', false) }
      }

      publishers {
        debianPackage('common') {
          commitMessage('Automatic Commit')
        }
        git {
          pushOnlyIfSuccess(true)
          branch('origin', '$GIT_BRANCH')
        }
      }

      runner('DontRun')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do something only if the conditions met, instead of not doing anything if the strings don't match?

Answer (score 3):

To *edit* the configuration, you have to place the `configure`-block below, not inside the publishers configuration:

```
job("flexible_condition") {
    publishers {
        flexiblePublish {
        //...
        }
    }

    configure { 
        it / publishers / 'org.jenkins__ci.plugins.flexible__publish.FlexiblePublisher' / publishers / 'org.jenkins__ci.plugins.flexible__publish.ConditionalPublisher' /  'runner'(class:'org.jenkins_ci.plugins.run_condition.BuildStepRunner$DontRun') {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing! Much easier! But the problem is default action in both cases would be 'Fail the build' and I can't change it to 'Run' or 'Don't Run'. Job Dsl plugin duplicates xml nodes instead of changing it to desirable value. P.S. I don't want to fail the build, I want to run/don't run action depending on condition.

Comment: I've put the configure block below as you suggested, and it almost helped. Now I have the action in right place in xml but still duplicated, see the UPD in my question.

Comment: BTW, I've removed double negation and set action to Run in case the check fails, and it didn't work as expected in Flexible Publish. In fact, action is not performing after check fails.

Comment: @Pangur then what do you want to achieve? If strings match, you want to perform an action, otherwise don't run anything?

Comment: nope. I want to do exactly the thing I've described. Natural condition (as if it was described with words) is "check if strings don't match; if check fails then do not run actions". Lets remove double negation: "check if strings match; if check fails then run actions". But in this case if check passes actions run anyway, too. This is not what I need. So I ought to use the first condition.

Comment: Ok, then I was confused by your description. Then of course, your initial condition (`not {stingsMatch(...)}`) was already correct.